# Laravel 10 policy не регистрируется

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-gate, laravel-policy

Столкнулся с проблемой регистрации `policy` в `Laravel 10`.

Есть стандартный модель и `crud` контроллер.

Вот пример контроллера.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Http\Requests\User\BusinessProfile\UpdateBusinessProfileRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\ErrorResource;
use App\Http\Resources\SuccessResource;
use App\Http\Resources\BusinessProfileResource;
use App\Repository\UserBusinessProfileRepositoryInterface;

final class UserBusinessProfileController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly UserBusinessProfileRepositoryInterface $userBusinessProfileRepository
    ){}

    public function update(int $id, UpdateBusinessProfileRequest $request): SuccessResource | ErrorResource
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        //My Code

        return SuccessResource::make([
            'message' => 'User business profile updated successfully',
            'data' => BusinessProfileResource::make($businessProfile)
        ]);
    }
}
```

И создан для него ՝UserBusinessProfilePolicy՝.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use App\Models\UserBusinessProfile;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class UserBusinessProfilePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\UserBusinessProfile  $userBusinessProfile
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, UserBusinessProfile $userBusinessProfile): bool
    {
        Log::info(111111);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Имена модели и политики в стандартах `laravel`․

В примерах все методы сокрощены. Но в когде они все есть, в стандарте.

И вот регистрация политики.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\UserBusinessProfile;
use App\Policies\UserBusinessProfilePolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        UserBusinessProfile::class => UserBusinessProfilePolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

    }
}
```

Дело в том что если смотреть на метод `update` в `policy` там я оставил лог.
Но все ровно код не даходит до этого. Как будто его вообще нет.

Все сделал так так написано в документации на [laravel 10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#registering-policies).

Кто может мне подсказать что я упустил? Или что там не так написано?

Как то очень не хочется по всем методам контроллера перейти и отдельно написать `gate`.

Comment: Не вижу где вы вызываете вашу политику

Comment: @Dinario Смотрите документацию.

Comment: @Dinario https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#registering-policies

Comment: Мне то документация не нужна. Я не про регистрацию политики, а про ее вызов. Не вижу этого в вашем коде.

Comment: Судя по вашему ответу, вы ее нигде не вызываете. Почитайте [этот раздел](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies). И выберите нужный вам способ

Comment: @Dinario Да, оно автоматически должно вызываться. Вставить всюду в методах не хочу. Эту версию знаю.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что Laravel должен автоматически предугадывать вашу логику? И автоматически вызывать политики, там где нужно вам? Это даже звучит странно. Увы, так это не работает

Comment: "Все сделал так так написано в документации на laravel 10" - не сделали

Comment: Чтобы заработало нужно проверять это через, к примеру, Gate::allows('update', UserBusinessProfile::class), либо привязывать через Gate::define.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov и это сделать в каждом методе контроллера ?

Comment: В методе проверять если у пользователя есть разрешение на выполнение действия, да. А как еще вы ожидали будет выполняться эта проверка? Вам даются инструмент, а уже далее нужно его настроить и прописать правила и/или проверку.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov вот что написано в доке.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#registering-policies

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если нужно все ровно каждый раз в методах прописать все это. То зачем этим способом регистрировать политики ? И без этого можно все это регистрировать. С кастомными методами в политике. Это должно быть автоматическая привязка к модели.

Comment: Мало ли что и как должно быть по вашему мнению. Есть framework, вы его используете, так что лучше изучите как в нем создается код для достижения результата. Не нравится - напишите свой, по своим правилам. Политики в Laravel - это оболочки, которые нужно наполнять смыслом.